# deployment package of your Lambda function is too large to enable inline code

Tags: aws-lambda, editor

After creating a AWS Lambda Function using Node JS 6.10 I cannot use the Inline Code Editor.

It has an error message:

> deployment package of your Lambda function is too large to enable inline code

How can I add code to the editor?

Comment: For some strange reason the first time I created a function - with 13 letters it came up with this error. When I tried again with a simpler name it worked. I then was unable to reproduce the problem after deleting and recreating the Lambda function with the original name.

Comment: I thought it was the ZIP size, since it should be less than 50MB

Comment: check this video out. well explained https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N56FtfXiD4A&list=PLmexTtcbIn_gP8bpsUsHfv-58KsKPsGEo&index=5&ab_channel=CompleteCoding

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you want inline code editing, the zipped deployment package should not exceed 3 MB. Also check out the other limits [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html#limits-list)

Comment: Good point. Also, worth noting that 'aws-sdk' is not needed to be installed. It is already made available by the AWS Lambda framework.  'aws-sdk' takes lot of space.

Comment: From what I found for Javascript, the aws-sdk version available by lambda is v2. Not v3. Might be helpful to know before you write all your code with v3 like I did.

Comment: Why AWS doesn't exclude node_modules from editing? Looks reasonable since you won't edit anything from packages source (and are the biggest part).